# convert a string that have a json format in a json file

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I have the following string which in json format:

```
arbre={"name":"flare","children":[{"name":"Algèbre","children":[{"name":"Nombres 
    Fractionnels","children":[{"name":"Addition fractionnelle","size":8.333333333333334},
    {"name":"Division fractionnelle","size":10.0}]},{"name":"nombre entier","children":
    [{"name":"division entière","size":15.0}]}]},{"name":"Geometrie dans l'espace","children":
    [{"name":"projection dans l'espace","children":[{"name":"sous chapitre1 projection dans 
    l'espace","size":10.0},{"name":"sous chapitre2 projection dans l'espace","size":15.0}]}]},
    {"name":"Physique","children":[{"name":"Onde","children":[{"name":"Onde 
    circulaire","size":15.0}]}]}]
}
```

I need to write this string into a json file with grails. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the JSON string is stored in a variable named `json`, the following should work

```
new File('/path/to/file.json').text = json
```